# How to count the same value in two table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called `hasil` and a table called `actual`. How can I write a SQL query to achieve the expected result in the following table ?

[image: awfe]]

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Could you please name your columns?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma yes I will edit it

Comment: @ImaningLarasati did you manage to solve your issue with some of the provided answerrs? You should accept one or provide your own. Please take a loot at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: OP - as Alexandre mentioned it might be best for you to close out your question by marking one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Hasil (id_data, label), Actual (id_data, label) and assuming you want an INNER JOIN (i.e: only passing on to your aggregation rows with common ids in both tables):

```
SELECT h_label, a_label, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM (
    SELECT h.label as h_label, a.label as a_label
    FROM hasil h, actual a 
    WHERE h.id_data = a.id_data) b 
GROUP BY h_label, a_label
```

In the inner subselect of the query you join your two tables using the id_data key in both of your tables to get this:

```
Id_data, hasil_label, actual_label
1, Yes, Yes
2, No, Yes
3, No, No
4, Yes, No
5, No, Yes
```

In the outer part of the query, you pick up the above result and do an aggregation (GROUP BY) with hasil_label and actual_label, using an aggregation function COUNT that will COUNT how many times such combination of hasil_label and actual_label occur.

This will result in:

```
hasil_label, actual_label, count
Yes, Yes, 1
No, Yes, 2
No, No, 1
Yes, No, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

**Prepare data**

```
create table hasil (id int, label varchar(10));
create table actual (id int, label varchar(10));
insert into hasil values (1,'Yes'), (2,'No'), (3,'No'), (4,'Yes'), (5,'No');
insert into actual values (1,'Yes'), (2,'Yes'), (3,'No'), (4,'No'), (5,'Yes');
```

**Query**

```
select hasil, actual, count(*)
from 
(
    select hasil.id, hasil.label as hasil, actual.label as actual
    from hasil
    inner join actual on hasil.id = actual.id
    order by 1
) x
group by hasil, actual
order by 1 desc, 2 desc;
```

**Result**

```
+-------+--------+----------+
| hasil | actual | count(*) |
+-------+--------+----------+
| Yes   | Yes    |        1 |
| Yes   | No     |        1 |
| No    | Yes    |        2 |
| No    | No     |        1 |
+-------+--------+----------+
```

**Explanation**

First, combine data from both tables by ID as common column between them.

```
select hasil.id, hasil.label as hasil, actual.label as actual
from hasil
inner join actual on hasil.id = actual.id
order by 1;
```

That'll give you:

```
+------+-------+--------+
| id   | hasil | actual |
+------+-------+--------+
|    1 | Yes   | Yes    |
|    2 | No    | Yes    |
|    3 | No    | No     |
|    4 | Yes   | No     |
|    5 | No    | Yes    |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Then, find how many unique combination of hasil+actual you have and then sort the data to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT a.label as Hasil, b.label as Actual, count(*)
FROM hasil a, actual b 
WHERE a.id_data = b.id_data
GROUP BY a.label, b.label
```